# Error when trying to open Campaign in Sitecore 7.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

I am using Sitecore 7.1, created a new campaign in Marketing center, but after saving when i try to open it, it gives the error `An error occurred while loading report data. Please try again or contact your administrator`.

Same happens with Engagement plans, i get this error when i try to open it `Error Loading Engagement Plan`.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the browser cache and restart browser, this usually helps.

Also. You need to approve the campaign through the workflow before publishing. And off course, make sure you have Sitecore DMS installed :-)

Comment: I think the issue here, like you mentioned, is they need to approve the campaign.  Though doing all the steps should help.